# Meaning of $ \Delta u \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ in the sense of distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have seen a sentence that says

$ \Delta u \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ in the sense of distributions.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In distribution theory, any function can be differentiated by applying the derivative to the other side

So if $U$ is a distribution and $f$ a test function 
$$
<D_i u, f > = -< u, D_i f>.
$$
This is a definition of $D_i u$ . Any bounded measurable function, $g,$ can be interpreted as a distribution via
$$
<g, f> = \int g(x) f(x) dx
$$
for test functions $f.$

If we compute $\Delta u$ using the distributional derivative and the resulting distribution agrees with that from an $L^{1}_{loc}$ function then we can say it is one.